# How can an object access the member of super class

Tags: scala

I write the following codes:

```
    class TestClass(val mem:Int)
    object TestObj extends TestClass(3){
      var sum = 5
      def apply(a : Int, b :Int, ext : TestClass) = sum + a + b + super.mem + ext.mem
    }
    println(TestObj(2,4,new TestClass(2))
```

when I deleted super.mem from method apply, these codes can be compiled successfully, so I want to know how can I access super member in object?

Comment: why not `this.mem` or just `mem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add `super.` in front of `mem`; just use `mem`, `TestObj` inherits it from its superclass `TestClass`.

```
class TestClass(val mem: Int)

object TestObj extends TestClass(3) {
  var sum = 5
  def apply(a: Int, b: Int, ext: TestClass) = sum + a + b + mem + ext.mem
}

println(TestObj(2, 4, new TestClass(2))
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But I still have a question: since the method of object is like a static method, why the normal member from inherited non-static class can be accessed by him directly. In java or c++, static method can only access class-level member not an instance-level member.

Comment: "since the method of object is like a static method" -- that idea has misled you here.  TestObj is an instance of some class, and that class extends TestClass.  Inheritance works as usual.  Singleton methods often serve the same purpose (but more cleanly) as static methods in Java, and in fact can be called as static methods *from* Java, but in Scala everything is really an object.